# JS library as standalone and jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build a small library and normally I would just make that either a standalone AMD module or, if it depends on jQuery functionality, as a jQuery plugin. For this one however, I realised that the library doesn't technically needs jQuery internally, though using it as a jQuery plugin would be more intuitive for jQuery users. 
Is it possible to write it in such way that it only registers as a jQuery module if jQuery is present but works just fine on it's own?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
if (typeof jQuery !== "undefined") {
    jQuery.fn.foo = function() { }
}
// jQuery(".selector").foo() is now available when jQuery was present
```